# Como simular produção em dev mantendo o sigilo de dados?

Tags: django

Quando ocorre algum erro em produção, o programador precisa simular o erro para corrigir. Porém não quero que o desenvolvedor tenha acesso a todos os dados de produção.

A solução que pensei foi ter um mecanismo de dump específico, onde eu gero um dump alterando os emails dos usuários, que é o que realmente seria confidencial.

Alguém já pensou em soluções para isto? Poderiam compartilhar suas experiências?

Answer (score 0):

O que é de costume de algumas empresas fazerem é:

- Um ambiente demo com dados fictícios o mais próximo das relações que o de produção teria
- Um ambiente de sandbox/preprod com dados de produção, para debug de algo que esteja acontecendo em produção e seria bem complicado de reproduzir em demo
- Ambiente de produção

A abordagem depende de qual problema você tem em mãos. Algumas vezes um problema que ocorre em produção, não será/seria possível de reproduzir em demo, ou no mínimo iria requerer um trabalho bem grande. Agora você realmente pode seguir nessa abordagem de criar um dump de produção e alterar os dados sensíveis, mas em alguns casos isso pode não ser suficiente pra reprodução do bug.

Comment: Sim. No meu contexto atual dev é o demo que você mencionou. O sandbox é que é um problema. Existem bugs que é realmente preciso pegar o contexto exato que ocorreu em prod para avaliar. Por isso pensei em fazer um dump alterarando os emails dos users, para manter em sigilo. Porém não consigo entender em como isso pode não ser suficiente para reproduzir o bug.

Comment: Também tenho dúvidas quanto as boas práticas e/ou soluções já desenvolvidas especificamente para este contexto.

Comment: Um exemplo meio esdrúxulo pro caso do email, mas que já aconteceu onde trabalho, é do usuário ter 2 emails diferentes num lugar onde deveriam ser iguais (models diferentes). Isso num dump que altera os emails, pode dificultar. Por esse motivo que empresas que vão pelo caminho de uma sandbox com dados de produção, sempre tem contratos de NDA bem específicos e rígidos.

Comment: As boas práticas e soluçoōes dependem de qual abordagem voce vai escolher. Mas algo que é bem pratico e tem sido bem utilizado sao ferramentas de CI/CD, como o Jenkins, que faz todo esse trabalho pra voce depois de um push/deploy